# GitLab Ldap insufficient access rights

Tags: ldap, gitlab

Right!

I am getting ldap to work with GitLab 7.2.1. I have the correct LDAP connection details posted below:

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['ldap_host'] = '## company url ##'
gitlab_rails['ldap_port'] = 389
gitlab_rails['ldap_uid'] = 'mail'
gitlab_rails['ldap_method'] = 'plain' # 'ssl' or 'plain'
gitlab_rails['ldap_bind_dn'] = ''
gitlab_rails['ldap_password'] = ''
gitlab_rails['ldap_allow_username_or_email_login'] = false
gitlab_rails['ldap_base'] = '## company bind ##'

gitlab_rails['gitlab_signup_enabled'] = 'true'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_default_projects_limit'] = 0
gitlab_rails['gitlab_default_can_create_group'] = false
```

I have the right username and password tested with others in my team. I have tried ssl and plain ldap on ports 389 & 636.

After wiresharking the traffic I found this:
[image]
However it returns:

```
Could not authorize you from LDAP because "Invalid credentials".
```

At the login page. which is a 49 response.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think `ldap_uid` should be the user allowed to search in the LDAP, and `ldap_password` is the password of this user. Also, your LDAP is  maybe "secured" & accessible only through `ldaps` protocol in `ldap_host`. Also change your `ldap_port` to `636`. Another thing you can try: `ldap_bind_dn` is the same than `ldap_base` but prefixed with `uid=<ldap_user>`, so something like `uid=my_user,ou=<company_bind>....`

Comment: Thank you, I have tried them all. I would post the config but due to company policy I am not allowed. 
We allow anonymous binding so the password and ldap_bind_dn can be blank. Tried SSl but internally plain and ssl are allowed.
The ldap_uid should be along the lines of "sAMAccountName", "mail","email" and "uid" as far as I know (can't remember where I read this sorry). Which is used for what feild you are searching for in LDAP. The "ldap_bind_dn" is the user to connect to LDAP. As we use anonymous binding then this does not matter.